# Web Services with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services

I'm working with the following tutorial:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ws-rubyrails/index.html

Everything after step 7 there results in a routing error.  I've made sure to gem install actionwebservice; I can't quite figure out how to get this running successfully.  I get this:

```
No route matches [GET] "/hello_message/invoke"
```

Thoughts?  I'm pretty new to rails so I could be overlooking something very trivial here.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you linked to is dated 2008, and Rails has come a long, long way in the last 6 years.  Are you sure you are using the Rails version listed on the article?  If you are using version 3+ instead of 2 as listed on the article, all kinds of things could be broken or inaccurate.

Even though it sounds like you have some time in on this project, I think you would be a lot better off going through something more recent like Rails in Action or Agile Web Development with Rails 4th edition, since version 2 is no longer being updated.

http://www.manning.com/katz/

http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails

Comment: Thanks for this.  I found that tutorial in an attempt to understand web services so that I can try to get WSO2 working with ruby - I posted another question here about that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523302/wso2-ruby-on-windows-how-to-run-security-sample

I'll mark this as answered given the age of the tutorial I referenced.  If you get a chance to look at my other question, I'd really appreciate any input. I've been spinning my tires with this for a couple days now :)